# How to append string at the end of text file without leading line break?

Tags: bash, shell

```sh
$ cat test.txt
foo

$ echo " bar" | tee -a test.txt
foo
 bar
```

Expected result for `cat test.txt` is `foo bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i~ '$ s/$/ bar/' test.txt
```

- `$` is an *address* that means "the last line". It applies to the following command.
- `s/$/ bar/` replaces `$`, i.e. the end of line, by  `bar`.
- `-i` (if supported) will change the file in place, leaving the original as a backup (renamed to `test.txt~`). If your sed doesn't support it, redirect the output to a new file and move it over the old one.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Is the `~` required? I tried without it and it worked on Debian.

Comment: @sunknudsen, with just `-i`, it won't leave a backup file. Note that the way `sed -i` takes its argument differs between the GNU and e.g. [FreeBSD versions of `sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `ed` over `sed -i` to edit files in place, as, unlike `sed -i`, it's standardized and works the same everywhere:

```sh
printf "%s\n" '$s/$/ bar/' w | ed -s test.txt
```

The commands are very similar; `sed` descended from `ed` as a way to work on text in the middle of a pipeline. The big change is `w` to **w**rite the changed file back to disk.